# File was uploaded but not found from admin and site

Tags: django, file-upload

**settings.py:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

**models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Photo(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo")

class Sale(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

**admin.py:**

```
class PhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Photo

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PhotoInline]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Sale)
```

After add a photo from admin I have exist photo in media directory and link to photo like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sale/product/1/photo/1.jpg
```

But when I go to this link I get message like this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sale/product/1/photo/1.jpg/
Product object with primary key u'1/photo/1.jpg' does not exist.
```

When I try to output my image to template like this:

```
src="{{ sale.product.photo_set.all.0.image.url }}"
```

I get link to photo like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/1.jpg
```

With error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/1.jpg
Using the URLconf defined in store.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
The current URL, photo/1.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

When I add MEDIA_URL = '/media/' nothing changed. I get one link in admin and site like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photo/1.jpg
```

And get second error

Comment: Are you on django dev server ?

Comment: Yes. Answer from [jpic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/136008/jpic) help me to solve my problem on dev server. What solution I must do on work server?

Comment: It depends, what's your production server ?

Comment: Production server is Apache 2.4 with mod_wsgi.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem was due to `MEDIA_URL` missing.

Now, your problem is that `MEDIA_URL` is not served.

Fix this by [serving media files from the devserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories).

Comment: I have django 1.6 and used last documentation by [serving media files from the devserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories)

Comment: I think that the new url is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development